chroma Insufficient budget available (open AI )
Runing this code and getting this error...
db = Chroma.from_documents(split_docs, OpenAIEmbeddings(), persist_directory=CHROMA_PATH)
ile ~/miniconda3/envs/rag/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py:1041, in SyncAPIClient._request(self, cast_to, options, remaining_retries, stream, stream_cls)
   1038         err.response.read()
   1040     log.debug("Re-raising status error")
-> 1041     raise self._make_status_error_from_response(err.response) from None
   1043 return self._process_response(
   1044     cast_to=cast_to,
   1045     options=options,
   (...)
   1049     retries_taken=options.get_max_retries(self.max_retries) - retries,
   1050 )

BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'code': None, 'message': 'Insufficient budget available', 'param': None, 'type': 'invalid_request_error'}}


The problem is not with ChromaDB or FAISS vector databases but that I did not have money in my openAI account. It was very hard to find the problem as I was looking for problems in ChromaDB and FAISS DB.
